# I can not delete or modify a product category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, delete

I have a problem with magento 1.9.1.0; I can not delete or modify a product category.
I look on the net but I have not found anything. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

TO delete/edit the category Follow These steps

1. Login to your admin panel
2. Go to Category > Manage Category
3. Click on the Product Category you want to delete/edit
4. Your category will be selected.

To delete a category click delete button and if you want to edit it change the information that you want to change and save the category

Or if you want to do it programmatically

```
$categoryId = 5; //id of the category that you wish to delete/edit
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($categoryId);
$category->delete() //to delete the category
```

for changing other information you may use setter and getters methods for the properties you want to change and then call save() method on category object.

1. Make sure you are loading the category that is under default category
2. Your magento index is up to date